# Let $F/K$ be a galois extension, $\alpha\in F$,and $H=\{\sigma\in G｜\sigma(\alpha)＝\alpha\}$ , to show $L^H＝K（α）$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F/K$ be a finite galois extension.
Let $G＝\text{Gal}(F/K)$, and $\alpha\in F$ and $H＝\{\sigma\in G｜\sigma(\alpha)＝\alpha\}$.
I want to show $K(\alpha)＝F^H$, where $F^H＝\{x\in F｜\forall\sigma\in H,\ \sigma(x)＝x\}$.

$K(\alpha)\subseteq F^H$ is clear, because $\sigma$ fixes $K$ and $\alpha$.
Could you prove other direction, $F^H\subseteq K(\alpha)$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You've been asking a lot of Galois theory questions. Don't you have a textbook to learn from?

Comment: Don't check the other inclusion, give a degree argument instead.

Comment: This is a basic ingredient in the Galois correspondence. Or possibly a consequence of the Galois correspondence. There are (at least) two slightly different routes to Galois correspondence. One (devised by Artin unless I'm mistaken) that uses groups of automorphisms as a starting point, and uses neat results like linear independence of characters) to get to the main results. And another using normality of splitting fields of (separable) polynomials as a starting point, proves the existence of prescribed number of automorphisms with those tools.

Comment: (cont'd) The latter works well over a prime field, and may have some pedagogical advantages, but it does not work as nicely in, say function fields. To be able to give a helpful answer to your question we absolutely need to know which route your source is going. And whether Galois correspondence has already been covered. In other words, we need [context as described in out guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Also, what Teddy38 said. Many a textbook would have this as a lemma or an example or as an exercise, depending.

Comment: For starters: 1) Have you already covered Galois correspondence or is this a step along the way (the latter alternative feels a bit less likely, but the latter route may go this way, particularly when relying on the existence of a primitive element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Show that the map $$\sigma H\mapsto \sigma(\alpha)$$
defines a bijection between the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$ and the set of conjugates of $\alpha$ over $K$. Conclude that $[K(\alpha):K]=[F^H:K]$ and hence $F^H=K(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $F^H$ is larger than $K(\alpha)$ then the extension being separable there is some non-trivial $\tilde{g}\in Hom_{K(\alpha)}(F^H,\overline{F})$. It extends to some $g\in Hom_{K(\alpha)}(F,\overline{F})$. Since $F/K$ is normal then $g(F)=F$ and $g\in Aut(F/K(\alpha))$. This $g$ is in $H$.

$\tilde{g}$ non-trivial means that some $\beta\in F^H$ is not fixed by $g$, a contradiction.